# PL/pgSQL SELECT into an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

Here's my function declaration and part of the body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION access_update()
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE team_ids bigint[];
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO team_ids "team_id" FROM "tmp_team_list";

    UPDATE "team_prsnl"
    SET "updt_dt_tm" = NOW(), "last_access_dt_tm" = NOW()
    WHERE "team_id" IN team_ids;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want `team_ids` to be an array of ints that I can then use in the `UPDATE` statement. This function give me errors like this:

```
psql:functions.sql:62: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "team_ids"
LINE 13:  AND "team_id" IN team_ids;
```

Comment: I think you got the order wrong in your select. Shouldn't that be: `SELECT team_id INTO team_ids FROM tmp_team_list;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Faster and simpler with a [**`FROM`** clause in your `UPDATE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html):

```sql
UPDATE team_prsnl p
SET    updt_dt_tm = now()
     , last_access_dt_tm = now()
FROM   tmp_team_list t
WHERE  p.team_id = t.team_id;
```

That aside, while operating with an array, the `WHERE` clause would have to be:

```
WHERE p.team_id = ANY (team_ids)
```

The `IN` construct works with lists or sets, not with arrays. See:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

Answer (score 5):

To create an array from a `SELECT`:

```
# select array(  select id from tmp_team_list ) ;
 ?column? 
----------
 {1,2}
(1 row)
```

The `IN` operator is [documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) as taking a subquery for the right-hand operand.  For example:

```
UPDATE team_prsnl SET updt_dt_tm = NOW()
 WHERE team_id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp_team_list);
```

Perhaps you can avoid the array altogether, or try supplying the array or `select from team_ids`.

Answer (score 0):

a tiny customization based on other answers.
If the `team_id` is a normal int data type.

```
   UPDATE team_prsnl p
    SET    updt_dt_tm = now()
          ,last_access_dt_tm = now()
    FROM   tmp_team_list t
    WHERE  p.team_id = any(array(select team_id from t));
```