# Select multiple rows as array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table where two people may have the same name, but separate IDs. I am given the name, and need to request their IDs.

When I use a command like:

```
SELECT id_num INTO cust_id FROM Customers WHERE name=CName;
```

If I use this command on the command line (psql), it returns 2 results (for example).

But when I use it as part of an SQL script (PL/pgSQL), it always just grabs the first instance.

I tried selecting into `cust_id[]`, but that produced an error. So what is the proper way to select ALL results, and pump them into an array or another easy way to use them?

Comment: there is example of use array in plpgsql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731481/pl-pgsql-select-into-an-array

Comment: the alternative to an array might be a loop? Is there a way to specify getting the 'next' result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In declare

```
  DECLARE id_nums bigint[];
```

in select

```
id_nums :=  ARRAY(select cust_id from Customers WHERE name = CName);
```

If you prefer loop use

```
DECLARE id_num bigint;

FOR id_num in select cust_id from Customers WHERE name = CName LOOP
  your code here
END LOOP;
```

Read plpgsql control structures in postgresql docs [9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

Comment: could you give a bit more explanation in regards to the Loop version?
id_num is my own variable, cust_id is a column in Customers.

I get an error that 'array value must start with "{" or dimension information. The context points to the FOR select statement.

Comment: Perfect, that was the problem I had delcared id_nums as an array.

I appreciate the thorough and easy to read response!

Comment: `FOR` loop looks fine, but the `SELECT INTO` example fails just like the one in the question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you have right I didn't tested it before. Corrected answer.

Answer (score 7):

To put data from individual rows into an array, use an [**array constructor**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
DECLARE id_nums int[];  -- assuming cust_id is of type int

id_nums := ARRAY (SELECT cust_id FROM customers WHERE name = cname);
```

Or the **aggregate function** [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)

```
id_nums := (SELECT array_agg(cust_id) FROM customers WHERE name = cname);
```

Or use `SELECT INTO` for the assignment::

```
SELECT INTO id_nums
       ARRAY (SELECT cust_id FROM customers WHERE name = cname);
```