# How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I used to have a query like in Rails:

```
MyModel.where(id: ids)
```

Which generates sql query like:

```
SELECT "my_models".* FROM "my_models"
WHERE  "my_models"."id" IN (1, 28, 7, 8, 12)
```

Now I want to change this to use `ANY` instead of `IN`. I created this:

```
MyModel.where("id = ANY(VALUES(#{ids.join '),('}))"
```

Now when I use empty array `ids = []` I get the folowing error:

```
MyModel Load (53.0ms)  SELECT "my_models".* FROM "my_models"  WHERE (id = ANY(VALUES()))
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
Position: 75: SELECT "social_messages".* FROM "social_messages"  WHERE (id = ANY(VALUES()))
    from arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:838:in `execute_query'
```

Comment: If you're going to write custom queries, please be **very** careful to use placeholders: `VALUES(?)` expanded as necessary with an array to bind is way better than what you have here. You need to be careful to properly escape any raw values being injected into your SQL. What's the purpose of this query?

Comment: in my real query i have so many IDs at the IN part so i want to optimise it using ANY in this case.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, `IN`  is an alias for `= ANY`

Comment: @PinnyM are you sure about this? I've been reading that we can dramatically improve the performance using ANY instead of IN (https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/2013/08/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/).

Comment: Where are all these ids coming from? Maybe you should be JOINing or using a subquery instead of sending a big list of ids to the database.

Comment: @PinnyM: `IN` is ***not*** an alias for `= ANY`. I provided details.

Comment: @EkiEqbal the article you've linked explains that using literal value lists is faster that using the Array type, not that ANY is faster than IN (ANY can handle both Arrays and value lists).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: you are correct, the docs use the term 'equivalent', and not 'alias' - my bad. However, since they are supposedly equivalent, do they actually have different query plans? If they do, I'm curious why the faster approach isn't always used. And if not, then why bother in this case?

Comment: @PinnyM: Actually, `IN` is rewritten with `= ANY` internally. I added details to my answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are two variants of `IN` expressions:

- [`expression IN (subquery)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN)
- [`expression IN (value [, ...])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR)

Similarly, two variants with the `ANY` construct:

- [`expression operator ANY (subquery)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME)
- [`expression operator ANY (array expression)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16)

A subquery works for either technique, but for the **second** form of each, `IN` expects a **list of values** (as defined in standard SQL) while `= ANY` expects an **array**.

#### Which to use?

`ANY` is a later, more versatile addition, it can be combined with any binary operator returning a boolean value. `IN` burns down to a special case of `ANY`. In fact, its second form is rewritten internally:

`IN` is rewritten with `= ANY`
`NOT IN` is rewritten with `<> ALL`

Check the `EXPLAIN` output for any query to see for yourself. This proves two things:

- `IN` can never be faster than `= ANY`.
- `= ANY` is not going to be substantially faster.

The choice should be decided by **what's easier to provide**: a list of values or an array (possibly as array literal - a single value).

If the IDs you are going to pass come **from within the DB** anyway, it is much more efficient to select them directly (subquery) or integrate the source table into the query with a `JOIN` (like [@mu commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-in-where-clause-with-rails-4-0-instead-of-in/31192557#comment50389756_31191507)).

To pass a ***long list*** of values from your client and get the best ***performance***, use an array, `unnest()` and join, or provide it as table expression using `VALUES` (like [@PinnyM commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#comment50425756_31192557)). But note that a `JOIN` preserves possible **duplicates** in the provided array / set while `IN` or `= ANY` do not. More:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91539/3684)

In the presence of NULL values, `NOT IN` is often the wrong choice and `NOT EXISTS` would be right (and faster, too):

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

#### Syntax for `= ANY`

For the array expression Postgres accepts:

- an [**array constructor**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) (array is constructed from a list of values on the Postgres side) of the form: `ARRAY[1,2,3]`
- or an [**array literal**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) of the form `'{1,2,3}'`.

To avoid invalid type casts, you can cast explicitly:

```
ARRAY[1,2,3]::numeric[]
'{1,2,3}'::bigint[]
```

Related:

- [PostgreSQL: Issue with passing array to procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963380/postgresql-issue-with-passing-array-to-procedure/27963713#27963713)
- [How to pass custom type array to Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009822/how-to-pass-custom-type-array-to-postgres-function/17840058#17840058)

Or you *could* create a Postgres function taking a `VARIADIC` parameter, which takes individual arguments and forms an array from them:

- [Passing multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109037/passing-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/28115702#28115702)

#### How to pass the array from Ruby?

Assuming `id` to be `integer`:

```
MyModel.where('id = ANY(ARRAY[?]::int[])', ids.map { |i| i})
```

But I am just dabbling in Ruby. @mu provides detailed instructions in this related answer:

- [Sending array of values to a sql query in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461042/sending-array-of-values-to-a-sql-query-in-ruby/22462519#22462519)

Comment: thanks man, this is WAY better :) aw how would I implement this in rails and activemodel? Thanks

Comment: Your solution working perfect except when I use empty array I get: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = text
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @EkiEqbal as Erwin stated above, add `::numeric[]` after the Array to avoid this problem.

Comment: @EkiEqbal: ... or `::int[]` in this case.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter considering that OP was trying to improve performance by using value lists instead of Arrays (on the assumption that [the linked article in above comments](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/2013/08/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/) still holds correct), the answer should use the format `VALUES (...), (...), ...` instead of `ARRAY[...]`.  Or did I miss something?  And if the article is no longer correct (or never was), then there doesn't really seem to be a point to this exercise...

Comment: @PinnyM: Seems like I missed your additional comment last year. You certainly got a point. I added a bit to address that above.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I tried your solution for ALL operator. the query is right. but it is not working as expected. Can you help me ?

Comment: @Vishal: Maybe. Ask your question as *question*. You can always link to this one for context and / or comment here with a link to the new question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I posted question from my friend's account. here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816759/all-operator-in-where-clause-in-rails It will be most helpful if you give solution.

Comment: For those that come by this answer like I did and find the discussion very useful - the datadog article linked by @PinnyM has changed to the following: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/