# How to aggragate integers in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that gives list of IDs:

```
ID
2
3
4
5
6
25
```

`ID` is `integer`.

I want to get that result like that in `ARRAY` of `integers` type:

```
ID
2,3,4,5,6,25
```

I wrote this query:

```
select string_agg(ID::text,',')
from  A
where .....
```

I have to convert it to text otherwise it won't work. `string_agg` expect to get `(text,text)`

this works fine the thing is that this result should later be used in many places that expect `ARRAY` of integers.

I tried :

```
select ('{' || string_agg(ID::text,',') || '}')::integer[]
from  A
WHERE ...
```

which gives: `{2,3,4,5,6,25}` in type `int4 integer[]`
but this isn't the correct type... I need the same type as `ARRAY`.

for example `SELECT ARRAY[4,5]`  gives `array integer[]`

in simple words I want the result of my query to work with (for example):

```
select *
from b
where b.ID = ANY (FIRST QUERY RESULT)   // aka: = ANY (ARRAY[2,3,4,5,6,25])
```

this is failing as ANY expect array and it doesn't work with regular integer[], i get an error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

note: the result of the query is part of a function and will be saved in a variable for later work. Please don't take it to places where you bypass the problem and offer a solution which won't give the `ARRAY` of `Integers`.

**EDIT**: why does

```
select *
from b
where b.ID = ANY (array [4,5])
```

is working. but

```
select *
from b
where b.ID = ANY(select array_agg(ID) from A where ..... )
```

doesn't work

```
select *
from b
where b.ID = ANY(select array_agg(4))
```

doesn't work either

the error is still:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/939860

Answer (score 1):

Expression `select array_agg(4)` returns set of rows (actually set of rows with 1 row). Hence the query

```
select *
from b
where b.id = any (select array_agg(4))  -- ERROR
```

tries to compare an integer (b.id) to a value of a row (which has 1 column of type integer[]). It raises an error.

To fix it you should use a subquery which returns integers (not arrays of integers):

```
select *
from b
where b.id = any (select unnest(array_agg(4)))
```

Alternatively, you can place the column name of the result of `select array_agg(4)` as an argument of `any`, e.g.:

```
select *
from b
cross join (select array_agg(4)) agg(arr)
where b.id = any (arr)
```

or

```
with agg as (
    select array_agg(4) as arr)
select *
    from b
    cross join agg
    where b.id = any (arr)
```

More formally, the first two queries use `ANY` of the form:

```
expression operator ANY (subquery)
```

and the other two use

```
expression operator ANY (array expression)
```

like it is described in the documentation: [9.22.4. ANY/SOME](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME)
and [9.23.3. ANY/SOME (array)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19712).

Answer (score 0):

How about this query? Does this give you the expected result?

```
SELECT *
FROM b b_out
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM b b_in 
              WHERE b_out.id = b_in.id 
                   AND b_in.id IN (SELECT <<first query that returns 2,3,4,...>>))
```

What I've tried to do is to break down the logic of `ANY` into two separate logical checks in order to achieve the same result.

Hence, `ANY` would be equivalent with a combination of `EXISTS` at least one of the values `IN` your list of values returned by the first `SELECT`.