# Use result of postgres CTE in function

Tags: postgresql

I am having difficulty using the results from a CTE in a function. Given the following Postgres table.

```
CREATE TABLE directory (
  id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  , name      TEXT
  , parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES directory(id)
);

INSERT INTO directory (name, parent_id)
VALUES ('Root', NULL), ('D1', 1), ('D2', 2), ('D3', 3);
```

I have this recursive CTE that returns the descendants of a directory.

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
  SELECT id
  FROM   directory
  WHERE  parent_id = 2

  UNION ALL

  SELECT directory.id
  FROM   directory, tree
  WHERE directory.parent_id = tree.id
)
```

The returned values are what I expect and can be made to equal an array

```
SELECT (SELECT array_agg(id) FROM tree) = ARRAY[3, 4];
```

I can use an array to select values from the table

```
SELECT * FROM directory WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[3, 4]);
```

However, I cannot use the results of the CTE to accomplish the same thing.

```
SELECT * FROM directory WHERE id = ANY(SELECT array_agg(id) FROM tree);
```

The resulting error indicates that there is a type mismatch.

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

However, I am unsure how to correctly accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM directory 
WHERE id = ANY(SELECT unnest(array_agg(id)) FROM tree);
```

See detailed explanation [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291503/how-to-aggragate-integers-in-postgresql/31292583#31292583).

Using `unnest()` in a subquery is a general method for dealing with arrays:

```
where id = any(select unnest(some_array))
```

Because `array_agg()` and `unnest()` are inverse operations, the query can be as simply as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM directory 
WHERE id = ANY(SELECT id FROM tree);
```

Comment: Why does the query also work when explicitly creating an array using `ANY(ARRAY[3, 4])`?

Comment: Because it is another form of the function: `any(array expression)` - gets all **elements** from the array. In the answer there is `any(subquery)`, which gets all **rows** from the subquery.