# Unwrapping row from SQL subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL subquery that always returns a single array. I want my outer query to filter where a value is in that array. Nothing I expect to work is working for this.

Setup for a minimal test:

```
CREATE TABLE test (num int);
INSERT INTO test (num) values (1);
INSERT INTO test (num) values (2);
```

My attempted query, which should return two rows, "1" and "2":

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE num = ANY(SELECT array_agg(num) from test);
```

Of course... `ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]`. The subquery returns one row containing an array, and I need to just get the array.

Also tried this without success:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE num = ANY((SELECT array_agg(num) from test)[0]);
```

I get `ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side`. THAT doesn't make sense to me, but I'm no expert.

What am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 4):

The first error is due to the fact that PostgreSQL sees

```
num = ANY(SELECT array_agg(num) from test)
```

as a form of

```
expression operator ANY (subquery)
```

instead of the one you want:

```
expression operator ANY (array expression)
```

As such, it tries to compare `num` to any **ROW** returned by the subquery (which in your example returns a single row `ARRAY[1,2]`), instead of every element of the array (hence the `operator does not exist: integer = integer[]` error you're getting). See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME) for more details.

---

The second errors simply comes from the fact that `[0]` accesses an element of an `integer[]`, and as such returns an `integer`. Since the right operand has to be an array (or a subquery, but PostgreSQL can't see one here), PostgreSQL returns `ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side`.
(As an aside, arrays are 1-based in PostgreSQL, not 0-based).

---

If you are sure that your function will always return a **single** array, then you can simply force Postgre to see `SELECT array_agg(num) from test`
as an `integer[]`:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE num = ANY((SELECT array_agg(num) from test)::integer[]);
┌─────┐
│ num │
├─────┤
│   1 │
│   2 │
└─────┘
(2 rows)
```

Note however that if your function returns multiple arrays, you will get an error (since a `setof integer[]` cannot be seen as an `integer[]`):

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE num = ANY((SELECT array_agg(num) from test GROUP BY num)::integer[]);
ERROR:  21000: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
LOCATION:  ExecSetParamPlan, nodeSubplan.c:970
```

---

Another solution is to use the `unnest` function to transform your array to a set of integer, using the `expression operator ANY (subquery)` form. This will work even if your function returns multiple array, though it is a bit slower than the previous query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE num = ANY(
  SELECT unnest(sub.array_agg)
  FROM (
    SELECT array_agg(num) FROM test GROUP BY num -- GROUP BY num to show off the multiple array scenario
  ) AS sub
);
┌─────┐
│ num │
├─────┤
│   1 │
│   2 │
└─────┘
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Also, a simple `where num = any(array(select num from test))` would work too.

Comment: Thanks, this is an excellent answer! I did it with a type cast because I'm sure it's only returning one array, and it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

[@Marth already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32407890/939860) details and some applications for the `ANY` construct. Closely related:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

There is simpler variant: use the subquery as **derived table** in the `FROM` clause and **join** to it:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   test t
JOIN  (SELECT array_agg(num) arr FROM test) a ON t.num = ANY(a.arr);
```

This even works if the subselect should return more than one row (with an array each). You get **every row from `test` that matches any element** of the array, but you get each row only ***once***. For an array '{1,1,2}', you get the same *two* rows as for '{1,2}'.

***Or*** **[`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)** and **join** to unnested elements without `ANY`. Conveniently use the same column name and join with the `USING` clause to merge the joined column. Then you can just `SELECT *` to get rows of just `test`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test t
JOIN   unnest((SELECT array_agg(num) arr FROM test)) num USING (num);
```

Here you get **one row for every element of the array**, so you get *three* result rows for '{1,1,2}'.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/97715/4)

`(SELECT array_agg(num) arr FROM test)` is just a dummy subquery for the proof of concept. But it should be mentioned at least once: if at all possible, don't aggregate in the first place, then you don't have to unnest later. Like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test t
JOIN   (SELECT num FROM test) t1 USING (num);
```