# Use Values from JSONB Array inside a WHERE IN Clause

Tags: arrays, postgresql, where-clause, jsonb, set-returning-functions

I have a `JSONB` object in PostgreSQL:

```
'{"cars": ["bmw", "mercedes", "pinto"], "user_name": "ed"}'
```

I am trying to use **values** from the "cars" array inside it in the `WHERE` clause of a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT car_id FROM cars WHERE car_type IN ('bmw', 'mercedes', 'pinto');
```

This will correctly return the values 1, 2, and 3 - see table setup at the bottom of this post.

Currently, in my function I do this:

```
(1) Extract the "cars" array into a variable `v_car_results`.
(2) Use that variable in the `WHERE` clause.

Pseudo code:

    DECLARE v_car_results TEXT
    BEGIN
        v_car_results = '{"cars": ["bmw", "mercedes", "pinto"], "user_name": "ed"}'::json#>>'{cars}';
            -- this returns 'bmw', 'mercedes', 'pinto'
        SELECT car_id FROM cars WHERE car_type IN ( v_car_results );
    END
```

However, the `SELECT` statement is not returning any rows. I know it's reading those 3 car types as a *single* type. (If I only include one `car_type` in the "cars" element, the query works fine.)

How would I treat these values as an *array* inside the `WHERE` clause?

I've tried a few other things:

1. The `ANY` clause.
2. Various attempts at *casting*.
3. These queries:

   ```
   SELECT car_id FROM cars
   WHERE car_type IN (json_array_elements_text('["bmw", "mercedes", "pinto"]'));

   ...
   WHERE car_type IN ('{"cars": ["bmw", "mercedes", "pinto"], "user_name": "ed"}':json->>'cars');
   ```

It feels like it's something simple I'm missing. But I've fallen down the rabbit hole on this one. (Maybe I shouldn't even be using the `::json#>>` operator?)

#### TABLE SETUP

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
   car_id SMALLINT
 , car_type VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO cars (car_id, car_type)
VALUES
  (1, 'bmw')
, (2, 'mercedes')
, (3, 'pinto')
, (4, 'corolla');

SELECT car_id FROM cars
WHERE car_type IN ('bmw', 'mercedes', 'pinto'); -- Returns Values : 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup>Assuming at least the current Postgres 9.5.</sup>

Use the set-returning function [`jsonb_array_elements_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) (as table function!) and ***join*** to the result:

```sql
SELECT c.car_id
FROM   jsonb_array_elements_text('{"cars": ["bmw", "mercedes", "pinto"]
                                 , "user_name": "ed"}'::jsonb->'cars') t(car_type)
JOIN   cars c USING (car_type);
```

Extract the JSON array from the object with `jsonb->'cars'` and pass the resulting JSON array (still data type `jsonb`) to the function. (The operator `#>` would do the job as well.)

Aside: `::json#>>` isn't just an operator. It's a cast to `json` (`::json`), followed by [the operator `#>>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE). You don't need either.

The resulting type `text` conveniently matches your column type `varchar(255)`, so we don't need type-casting. And assign the column name `car_type` to allow for the syntax shorthand with `USING` in the join condition.

This form is shorter, more elegant and typically a bit faster than alternatives with `IN ()` or `= ANY()` - which would work too. Your attempts were pretty close, but you need a variant with a ***subquery***. This would work:

```
SELECT car_id FROM cars
WHERE  car_type IN (SELECT json_array_elements_text('["bmw", "mercedes", "pinto"]'));
```

Or, cleaner:

```
SELECT car_id FROM cars
WHERE  car_type IN (SELECT * FROM json_array_elements_text('["bmw", "mercedes", "pinto"]'));
```

Detailed explanation:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

Related:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much! That was absolutely killing my day! :-)

Comment: You now what? I didn't see your updated solution. That definitely looks cleaner. I'll go with that one!

Comment: Erwin you seem to be a helpful expert fixing postgresql queries in most of the questions i have seen. Do you know what the problem is with the sql query in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679190/rails-postgresql-9-5-querying-jsonb-column-containing-array-of-hashes