# Selecting array values with IN clause

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with the array field and with the following values:

[image]

I want to pull all the rows which have an `id` value in the `field` column and here is the query I tried (now simplified with table alias):

```
SELECT tb1."id",
       tb1."field",
       tb1."field1"
FROM "polls_nullableintegerarraymodel" tb1
WHERE tb1."field" IN (ARRAY[tb1."id"])
```

But for some reason it does not pull the values.

Comment: There are various ways to read your question. Please clarify. Provide data as *text* not as screenshot. Provide your Postgres version and table definition, make the example meaningful and add the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I am expecting something like this:

```
SELECT am."id", am."field", am."field1"
FROM "polls_nullableintegerarraymodel" am
WHERE am."id" = ANY(am."field");
```

Also, notice how table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.

EDIT:

Here is sample code that shows this working:

```
with t as (
      select 1 as id, '{2}'::integer[] as field1 union all
      select 2 as id, '{1, 2}':: integer[] as field1
     )
select *
from t
where id = any(field1);
```

This returns only the second row.

EDIT II:

You seem to want this:

```
SELECT tb1."id", tb1."field", tb1."field1"
FROM "polls_nullableintegerarraymodel" tb1
WHERE tb1."field" <@ (SELECT array_agg("id") FROM tb1);
```

This is probably a simple way to accomplish what you want, but this appear to be what you are attempting.

Comment: My requirement is slightly different. I want to check if the arrayfield contains any id values. Updated with the alias.

Comment: That makes no sense.  `id` is a number, not an array.  The second column is the array.

Comment: I want to convert all the ids into a array and evaluate against the field1 column.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> I want to check if the arrayfield contains any id values

This query returns all rows where the array in `field` contains *any* `id` value from the same table (not just the same row):

```
SELECT *
FROM   polls_nullableintegerarraymodel p1
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   polls_nullableintegerarraymodel p2
   WHERE  p2.id = ANY(p1.field)
   );
```

Using the `ANY` construct In an [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) expression:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

The same with [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM   polls_nullableintegerarraymodel p1
WHERE  field && (ARRAY(SELECT id FROM polls_nullableintegerarraymodel));
```

Using the overlaps operator `&&` and a simple [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) (faster than `array_agg()` in simple cases).

But I expect performance of this variant to deteriorate with big tables, since the assembled array grows equally big.