# Find parent records where associated records are not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

Here is the association what i have .

*award_test.rb*

```
has_many :instructor_student_awards , :dependent => :destroy
has_many :award_test_payment_notifications, dependent: :destroy
```

*instructor_student.rb*

```
has_many :instructor_student_awards, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :awards, through: :instructor_student_awards
has_many :award_test_payment_notifications, dependent: :destroy
```

*instructor_student_award.rb*

```
belongs_to :award
belongs_to :instructor_student
belongs_to :award_test
```

*award_test_payment_notification.rb*

```
belongs_to :award_test
belongs_to :instructor_student
```

*schema.rb*

```
"award_tests"
    t.date     "test_date"
    t.time     "test_time"
    t.integer  "award_id"
    t.decimal  "test_fee"


"award_test_payment_notifications"
    t.text     "response_params"
    t.string   "status"
    t.string   "transaction_id"
    t.string   "paid_by"
    t.float    "amount"
    t.string   "merchant_reference"
    t.integer  "award_test_id"
    t.integer  "instructor_student_id"

 "instructor_student_awards"
    t.integer  "instructor_student_id"
    t.integer  "award_test_id"
    t.boolean  "is_registered",         default: false
```

Any instructor student can register in award tests. one instructor student can register in multiple award tests.
  instructor student have to pay fee for giving test in award test. instructor student can pay in 2 ways for award test.

1. online
2. cash

when instructor student pay for that award test. than instructor student and award_test data will be insert in `award_test_payment_notifications`. award_test_notifications table have all the field related to student and award tests.

if the instructor student don't pay for that award test than it becomes unpaid, so the award test payment notifications will be nil in that condition only for that award test.

**instructor student 1 register for 3 award tests like 10,11,12.**

**instructor student 1 paid cash for award test 10.**

**instructor student 1 paid online for award test 12.**

**instructor student 1 didn't paid for award test 11.**

**so instructor student has 2 award test payment notifications 
  1) for award test 10 2) award test 12**

When i search for award tests between 1 jan 2017 to 31 july 2017. and this 3 awards belongs to in this filter 
    than instructor student 1 will be return for 3 categories.

1. cash payment
2. online payment
3. unpaid

i have 2 dates and i need to filter data based on the 2 dates. that date will be test date . i have to differentiate all the cash payments , online payments and unpaid .

Here is what query i made for getting cash payments and  online payments.

```
current_admin_award_test = AwardTest.joins(instructor_student_awards: {:instructor_student => :award_test_payment_notifications}).where("test_date <= ? AND test_date >= ? AND instructor_student_awards.instructor_student_id  IN (?) ", @endMonth.end_of_month, @startMonth.beginning_of_month, @all_instructor_student_ids)

@award_test_cash = current_admin_award_test.joins("INNER JOIN award_test_payment_notifications atn ON award_test_payment_notifications.award_test_id = award_tests.id").where("award_test_payment_notifications.paid_by = ? ","Cash").select("DISTINCT(award_tests.id), instructor_student_awards.instructor_student_id, award_test_payment_notifications.paid_by, award_tests.test_fee, award_tests.test_date")

@award_test_paid_online = current_admin_award_test.joins("INNER JOIN award_test_payment_notifications atn ON award_test_payment_notifications.award_test_id = award_tests.id").where("award_test_payment_notifications.paid_by <> ? ","Cash").select("DISTINCT(award_tests.id), instructor_student_awards.instructor_student_id, award_test_payment_notifications.paid_by, award_tests.test_fee, award_tests.test_date")
```

It is working fine . but i am stuck how to get unpaid award tests list for one instructor students multiple award tests.

**Update 1**

> what is the role of InstructorStudentAward ?
>
> When instructor student register award test.  the data logged in
>   instructor student awards.
>
> if any payment is logged for that AwardTest, the event is assumed to
>   be paid-in-full. OK?
>
> Yes. when instructor student paid for award test. award test payment
>   notifications will be logged in not matter what is amount.
>
> Is an InstructorStudentAward association created for every
>   InstructorStudent that registers for an AwardTest?
>
> Yes , you are right .
>
> So what you want is, any InstructorStudentAward JOIN AwardTest JOIN
>   InstructorStudent pair that is missing an associated
>   AwardTestPaymentNotification
>
> Yes
>
> Can I assume you're using PostgreSQL database
>
> Yes, I am using PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I added this github repo with the parts of your question that I needed (and a few things you didn't mention) to replicate your association structure.

https://github.com/kingdonb/ashvin-stackoverflow-post

`example.rb` in the project root is a Rails Runner script that I imagine replicates approximately how these things are created and linked together.

Your queries, reformatted to be a bit readable:

```
current_admin_award_test = AwardTest.joins(
  instructor_student_awards: {
    :instructor_student => :award_test_payment_notifications
  }).where("test_date <= ? AND test_date >= ?
    AND instructor_student_awards.instructor_student_id
    IN (?) ",
  @endMonth.end_of_month,
  @startMonth.beginning_of_month, @all_instructor_student_ids)

@award_test_cash = current_admin_award_test.joins(
  "INNER JOIN award_test_payment_notifications atn ON
  award_test_payment_notifications.award_test_id = 
    award_tests.id").
  where(
    "award_test_payment_notifications.paid_by = ? ", "Cash"
  ).select(
  "DISTINCT(award_tests.id),
   instructor_student_awards.instructor_student_id,
   award_test_payment_notifications.paid_by,
   award_tests.test_fee, award_tests.test_date")

@award_test_paid_online = current_admin_award_test.joins(
  "INNER JOIN award_test_payment_notifications atn ON
  award_test_payment_notifications.award_test_id =
    award_tests.id").
  where(
    "award_test_payment_notifications.paid_by <> ? ","Cash"
  ).select(
  "DISTINCT(award_tests.id),
   instructor_student_awards.instructor_student_id,
   award_test_payment_notifications.paid_by,
   award_tests.test_fee, award_tests.test_date")
```

The missing query I think, CAN'T be derived from `current_admin_award_test`, if you meant to do that, because it's silently doing an Inner Join.  When you say "joins" with no additional context, Rails infers that you mean Inner Join: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins#docs_body

Look at the results of this:

```
current_admin_award_test = AwardTest.joins(
  instructor_student_awards: {
    :instructor_student => :award_test_payment_notifications
  })
```

You get back only paid InstructorStudentAwards!

So it is dropping records that don't have matching AwardTestPaymentNotifications, because Inner Join requires a match on both sides to produce a row result.  So it won't return any records that are unpaid, ever, if you start your query from that association object.

You want:

```
@award_test_unpaid = AwardTest.left_outer_joins(
  instructor_student_awards: {
    instructor_student: :award_test_payment_notifications
  }).where(award_test_payment_notifications: { id: nil } ).

[ and the rest of your criteria from current_admin_award_test ]

  where("test_date <= ? AND test_date >= ?
    AND instructor_student_awards.instructor_student_id
    IN (?) ",
  @endMonth.end_of_month,
  @startMonth.beginning_of_month, @all_instructor_student_ids)
```

If you are using an older version of Rails, it gets more complicated because `#left_outer_joins` was only added in Rails 5.0.

If you want to improve this, you could make current_admin_award_test into a parameterized scope that does not join `award_test_payment_notifications` (you are already joining that table to make each derived payment status list, I'm afraid this joins twice and that might be why you had to resort to using DISTINCT...? or was there another reason?)

Maybe they had multiple AwardTestPaymentNotifications for one AwardTest and you didn't want to get back duplicate AwardTest records from that.  OK.  You can also use this new scope as the basis for your `@award_test_unpaid`.

```
scope :current_admin_award_test, ->(
  end_date, begin_date, instructor_student_list) {
    joins(instructor_student_awards: :instructor_student).
    where("test_date <= ? AND test_date >= ?",
      end_date.end_of_month, begin_date.beginning_of_month).
    where(instructor_student_awards:
      { instructor_student: instructor_student_list }
    )
  }
```

([in context](https://github.com/kingdonb/ashvin-stackoverflow-post/commit/543c04d2737e4b7c9bc48806c874a589313aa25c) at the GitHub project) I put this in a commit where it goes on the AwardTest model.

Your three private variables could also be scopes, with the same parameters (passing them through to this master scope, that handles the date logic.)

(Within giving the benefit of the doubt, you might have these things in your model already, but were simply not including them in the question because you didn't want to put too much code in it.)

So if an InstructorStudent hasn't paid one of his bills, his AwardTest will show up in this list.  And if all of the bills are paid, InstructorStudent will not show up in this list.  I think that's what you were trying to achieve?

If you wanted to further derive a list of `InstructorStudent` records that have unpaid bills, so you can send them each one strongly worded email, now it looks like just like this:

```
@award_test_unpaid.
  map(&:instructor_student_awards).flatten.
  map(&:instructor_student).
  map(&:id).uniq
```

For a bonus, I just spent some time on the repo I stood up, fleshing out rails associations and scopes so that there is a current_unpaid scope that does roughly what you wanted.

```
scope :current_unpaid, ->(
  end_date, begin_date, instructor_student_list) {
  current_admin_award_test(end_date, begin_date, instructor_student_list).
    left_outer_joins(:award_test_payment_notifications).
      where(award_test_payment_notifications: { id: nil } )
  }
```

---

2017-08-04 Edit: @ashvin revealed he was on Rails 4.1, so `.left_outer_join` won't work because it wasn't added until Rails 5... this raw SQL will work in its place, though:

```
 scope :current_unpaid, ->(
   end_date, begin_date, instructor_student_list) {
   current_admin_award_test(end_date, begin_date, instructor_student_list).
     joins("LEFT JOIN award_test_payment_notifications
             ON award_tests.id =
                award_test_payment_notifications.award_test_id
            AND instructor_students.id =
                award_test_payment_notifications.instructor_student_id").
       where(award_test_payment_notifications: { id: nil } )
   }
```

---

Then you can

```
AwardTest.current_unpaid(Date.today, Date.today, InstructorStudent.all.map(&:id))
```

and get a list of all unpaid AwardTests in the current month!

This depends on setting `has_many :award_test_payment_notifications` on the `AwardTest` model.  It also depends on the `current_admin_award_test` scope that we defined further above.  All of the changes to make that work are in this commit: [more time on rails associations](https://github.com/kingdonb/ashvin-stackoverflow-post/commit/83b0a5d385118b988be3bc3d65c428a14119fd59).  Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes. i updated my question and given answer to your question .  :)

Comment: @ashvin I think I solved it in Pure Rails.  Hopefully you're on Rails 5.0 or newer!

Comment: No, rails version is  4.1.1.

Comment: Snap!  Then wherever I said .left_outer_join( you need to write .joins("LEFT JOIN [table] ON ...").

I will take a knife to my commits and rebase them on top of a Rails 4.1 project later on in the evening, then prepare another edit for my question, but if you can apply the solution (as it should need only minimal changes for the older database support) please upvote!  And please edit your question again to include this, as it has turned out to be important information.

Comment: @ashvin I added a version of the final "scope-based" answer that writes the `LEFT JOIN` out as raw SQL, so it will work with older versions of Rails.  You should really consider upgrading!  I am on Rails 4.2.7.1 and I should follow my own advice, too.

Comment: @ashvin Check it out :D