# Having clause in PostgreSql with association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Here is the association i have

```
Instructor has many Instructor Students

InstructorStudent has many Student Contacts
```

Student Contacts table has one field primary_contact which has boolean type.

I want to instructor students who has not any student contacts or all
 student contacts's primary_contact is false.

> e.g
>
> instructor student 1 has 3 student contacts  and all 3 student
>   contacts's primary contact field is false. than i want that record
>
> instructor student 2 has 3 student contacts in which 2 student
>   contacts's primary contact field is false and other student contact's
>   primary contact is true than i dont want that record.

i made one query but i dont how to write having clause.

`Instructor.joins(:instructor_students => :student_contacts)
   .where("admin_users.id = ? AND student_contacts.primary_contact = 
   ?",7,false)
 .select("student_contacts.instructor_student_id,count(student_contacts.primary_contact) as sc_count")
.group("student_contacts.instructor_student_id")
.having("count(student_contacts.primary_contact) = ?",Dynamic_value)`

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, as you said you want `InstructorStudent` object so you should join on that table.

```
InstructorStudent.joins(:student_contacts).where("student_contacts.primary_contact = 
   ?",false)
  .select("student_contacts.instructor_student_id,count(student_contacts.primary_contact) as sc_count")
    .group("student_contacts.instructor_student_id")
    .having("count(student_contacts.primary_contact) = ?",Dynamic_value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i dont want InstructorStudent object i need instructor student's id that's why i added it in `select`. my question is difference. have you read it ?