# Postgres IN clause with many values not using partial index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, sql-in

I am using Postgres 9.2.24.

I have a table named `_order` with about 100,000,000 rows. The table has a column named `merged_id int8`. About 2,000,000 of the `_order` rows have a `merged_id` value, the rest has null.

I find two different Postgres behavior where I search `_order` use the query

```
select * from _order where merged_id in ( 10001 ,10002 ,10003 ....., 11000);
```

If I create an index like this:

```
create index order_merged_id_index on _order(merged_id);
```

No matter how many ids in in clause (test from 1 to 50 to 100 to 200 to 1000) `EXPLAIN` shows the search will use `index_scan`.

But if I create this partial index instead:

```
create index order_merged_id_index on _order(merged_id) where merged_id is not null;
```

`EXPLAIN` shows a `seq_scan` for more than 100 id numbers in the `WHERE` clause.

Why is this?
And is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running an [outdated version of Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Consider upgrading soon.

There are many possible reasons. I suspect a weakness in the selectivity estimation of the outdated version. I vaguely remember a maximum of 100 values for query planning involving arrays that was later improved. `IN` expressions are typically transformed to `= ANY (ARRAY[...]`) internally:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

Either way, you might be able to fix the behavior by repeating the predicate of the partial index in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM _order 
WHERE merged_id IN ( 10001 ,10002 ,10003 ....., 11000)
AND   merged_id is not null;  -- logically redundant
```

There may be other problems with your server configuration like cost settings or table statistics:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

And don't forget to run `ANALYZE` on your table at least once after creating the partial index. Or, preferably, `VACUUM ANALYZE`, but that's more expensive for your big table.

- [PostgreSQL partial index unused when created on a table with existing data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99323/postgresql-partial-index-unused-when-created-on-a-table-with-existing-data/99324#99324)

However, for long lists of values, there are more efficient query variants to begin with:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM   unnest('{10001 ,10002 ,10003 ....., 11000}'::int8[]) merged_id
JOIN   _order o USING (merged_id);
```

See:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in/91539#91539)

Comment: Thanks so much for giving me advice.