# how to delete if not exists in postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postman

```js
for (var i in req.body.categories) {
  db.query("DELETE FROM guide_categories WHERE NOT IN($1) AND guide_id = $1",[req.body.categories[i],req.params._id], function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('updated');
  })                                
}
```

I am trying to delete if not exists in the array and I am passing the array from postman like `categories:["3","2","1"]`. How to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- don't use a loop over the categories. Doing that, you will delete everything (first time you delete everything but category 3, so you only have category 3 left, then you delete except category 2, so you delete everything).
- you're missing a column name before `NOT IN`.
- do not use `NOT IN`, but `<> ALL`, and pass the entire array
- Fix the second `$1`.

So it should probably something along the lines of:

```
  db.query("DELETE FROM guide_categories WHERE category_id <> ALL ($1) AND guide_id = $2",
      [
          req.body.categories,
          req.params._id
      ],
      function(err, data)
  {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('updated');
  })
```

Comment: what is this "<>" symbol represents??

Comment: Not equal, as in basic SQL.

Comment: will it not delete string values??

Comment: It will delete data from the `guide_categories` table only, which as far as I understand from what little information you provided is a join table which should only contain the ids of the categories and guides.

Comment: `db.query('DELETE FROM position WHERE position <> ALL ($1) AND user_id=$2 RETURNING *',[data.positionDetails.position,companyuser.rows[0]._id],function(err,data1){
  if (err) return callback(new Error(err));                             
})`  here it is deleting all values.

Comment: It is deleting everything you're asking it to delete, i.e. all rows in the `position` table where `position` is not `data.positionDetails[i].position` and `user_id` is `companyuser.rows[0]._id‌`. If that's not what you want, you'll need to open a new question on this topic with all relevant info, as this is completely unrelated to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

3 errors stand out:

1. The column name (`category`?) in front of `IN` is missing in the query, making the statement illegal syntax.
2. You are using the same parameter `$1` twice. The second one should probably be `$2`.
3. The `IN()` construct expects a list of values or a subquery, *not* an array. While you pass an array, use `<> ALL()` instead.

This query should work:

```
DELETE FROM guide_categories
WHERE category <> ALL($1)
AND guide_id = $2;
```

Careful with NULL values, though!
Details:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)