# Pass VARIADIC argument into IN in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to build a Postgres function that takes table names as variadic argument and outputs the query, that returns select string from  `information_schema` like

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM table2
```

So far I made following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION query_tables(VARIADIC list text[])
    RETURNS text
AS $$
DECLARE
    qry TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT string_agg(
        format('SELECT *
            FROM %1$I', table_name),
        ' UNION ')
    INTO qry
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
          AND table_name IN (list);

    return qry;
END;
$$
```

So it can be called like this `SELECT * FROM query_tables('table1','table2');`

However, I'm stuck at `IN (list)` where I'm not able to pass that variadic argument in `IN()`.

Is it possible?

Comment: `table_name IN (list)` change to `table_name = ANY (list)`

Comment: Daym!, that works. Post it as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an *array*, change

`table_name IN (list)` to `table_name = ANY (list)`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html

> expression operator ANY (array expression)

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/5315974

Comment: Thank you @Erwin Brandstetter