# Ecto on Postgres: Generate `in (...)` query

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have an Ecto query that finds rows with a column in a set of values. Something like this (using a fictitious blog domain):

```
Post
|> where(state in ^["published", "draft"])
```

This generates a clause like this:

```
p0.state = ANY($1)
```

With `["published", "draft"]` as parameters.

The database is Postgres 9.6. Running explain shows the cost of this query is much higher (by many orders of magnitude) than what is [supposed to be the equivalent clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557):

```
p0.state in ($1)
```

I do have an index on `state`.

I don't know if this due to a performance problem in Postgres itself, but I've found some hints of that.

I'd like to either be able to work around the performance issue or influence Ecto to generate `p0.state in ($1)` instead.

Any advice?

Comment: In the question you linked to, the first answer says "In fact, its second form is rewritten internally: IN is rewritten with = ANY". Where did you read that `= ANY` is "many orders of magnitude" slower than `IN`?

Comment: I didn't read it, that's the result of running `explain` on both versions on my DB.