# How to build query with separate, identical WHERE conditions on multiple columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Let's assume I have the table with below columns and records:

```
id shop_id product_id
1  1       1
2  1       2
3  2       1
4  2       2
```

I want to run single query to get ID 1 and ID 4 records when query looks like this one:

```rb
ShopProduct.where(shop_id: 1, product_id: 1).where(shop_id: 2, product_id: 2)
```

The problem is that when I try to simplify the query like this, I get all four records:

```
ShopProduct.where(shop_id: [1,2], product_id: [1,2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two conditions are independent. This achieves a "step-lock" like you desire:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   "ShopProduct"
WHERE  shop_id IN (1,2)
AND    product_id = shop_id; -- !
```

Or:

```sql
...
WHERE  shop_id = ANY ('{1,2}'::int[])
...
```

For best performance, have an index on `shop_id` or `(shop_id, product_id)` with this. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Should be something like this in Ruby:

```rb
ShopProduct.where('shop_id = ANY(ARRAY[?]::int[]) AND product_id = shop_id', ids.map { |i| i})
```

See:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

Comment: But will it work if I change query to `ShopProduct.where(shop_id: 1, product_id: 1).where(shop_id: 2, product_id: 3)`? So shop_id does not equal product_id. Assuming that we have this extra record in the database.

Comment: @HubertJakubiak: No, that's a different problem then. Your question indicated equality for both. Maybe ask another question? (There are solutions ...) Also define the use case more closely while being at it: few number pairs or long lists? Small or big table? Postgres version? Can matter for the best solution.

Comment: Sorry, for bad example. Thanks for your input.