# How to formulate a WHERE condition with array input?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

We have a table with names and their IDs like:

```
 1 | John
 2 | Mary
 3 | Ann
 ...
```

An array of IDs is given. For example, `{1,4,7}`. I need to get an array of names, which corresponds to these IDs.

How should I formulate the `WHERE` condition?
And how to return an array?

Answer (score 1):

To pass an array and receive an array:

```
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT name FROM tbl WHERE id = ANY ('{1,4,7}'));
```

I am passing an [array literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) (a constant). Works without cast while the element type of the array can be coerced to the type derived from the compared column type. Else, add an explicit type cast to the array:

```
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT name FROM tbl
              WHERE id = ANY ('{2021-01-03, 2021-01-04}'::date[]))
```

About `IN` vs. `= ANY`:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)
- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

About the [array constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)

Answer (score 0):

use the IN clause

```
Select name from table1 where id in (1,4,7)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: It should return an array, not a columns

Comment: And we are given an array, not list. It is the condition of exercise I have.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative: `unnest` (normalize) the array, join with the table and then aggregate:

```sql
select array_agg(t."name") 
from the_table t
join unnest('{1,4,7}'::integer[]) aid on t.id = aid;
```

or using `array` constructor

```sql
select array
(
 select t."name" 
 from the_table t
 join unnest('{1,4,7}'::integer[]) aid on t.id = aid
);
```