# How to check if value in subset of array in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want put a condition in my WHERE clause that returns true if a text field is contained in a subset of an array declared in the statement. This is using postgres v15.1.  I have simplified the statement to the following example:

```
SELECT 'case_1'::TEXT IN((ARRAY['case_1','case_2','case_3']) [1:2]);
```

This should declare an array containing the case_1,2,3, take a subset of the array containing case_1,2 and then test if case_1 is in the array. Expected result is true.

Actual behaviour is an error: "Operator does not exist text=text[]".

I understood the IN() operator is a test if the left hand argument is in the right hand argument which has a dimension.

How can I correct the syntax to return true or false if case_1 is in the subset of the array?

Comment: Details for `IN` vs `ANY`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/939860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, you've got your types messed up.

The `IN` keyword expects an explicit list of items in brackets. You have provided it with one item - an array.

You want `ANY(...)`

```
SELECT 'case_1' = ANY((ARRAY['case_1', 'case_2', 'case_3'])[1:2]);
```

Comment: Yes this was the problem.